# Do the <%= %> tags change the type of variable? Passed variables are not working inside my function

Tags: ejs

I passed information from mongoDB using mongoose to my ejs file. From here I am trying to loop the data through a function called addMarker that pulls the data with a <%= %> tag and adds it to a google map.

I have tested the values by printing them and their "typeof" to the console and they show that they are correct (Number,number, string) and the correct value. So my assumption is either the way I am passing the values is invalid or the <%= %> tags are changing the type of the variable. I have also tried using <%- and <% tags

ejs

```
<script> 
        function initMap(){
            //Map Options to dictate zoom and position
            var options = {
                zoom: 16, 
                center: {lat:35.6543936, lng: -97.4714266}
            }
            //init map for view
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

            /*var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position:{lat: 35.654243, lng: -97.472937 },
                map: map,
                title: 'Math And Computer Science'
            });*/

            //addMarker({coords:{lat:35.6543936, lng: -97.4714266}, title: "TestCase"});
            //addMarker({coords:{lat:35, lng: -97}, title: "TestCase2"});

            <% for (const location of results) { %>
               addMarker({coords:{lat: <%=location.lat %>, lng: <%=location.lng%> }, title: <%=location.title%> } );
               <%= console.log(location.lat) %>
               <%= console.log(typeof location.lat) %>
               <%= console.log( location.title) %>
            <% } %>


            //Add Marker Function
            function addMarker(props){
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: props.coords,
                    map:map,
                    title: props.title
                })
            }
        }
</script>
```

So I have commented out tests of addMarker:

```
            //addMarker({coords:{lat:35.6543936, lng: -97.4714266}, title: "TestCase"});
            //addMarker({coords:{lat:35, lng: -97}, title: "TestCase2"});
```

that both work as intended. When I run addMarker in my loop the map shows up but no markers are displayed on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see source of script in browser to see generated code.

Code <% is execute on server and then generated js execute in browser.

For example you need to include your title in " ' " and use js function outside <% (example for console.log):

```
         <% for (const location of results) { %>
           addMarker({coords:{lat: <%=location.lat %>, lng: <%=location.lng%> }, title: '<%=location.title%>' } );
           console.log( <%= location.lat %> ); 
           console.log( <%= typeof location.lat %> );
           console.log( '<%= location.title %>' ); 
        <% } %>
```

Comment: Ah i see. I didn't know that even though it is a String you need to surround it in quotes like that.